# Laravel 5 Error installing wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3, I want to install wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php, when i add composer require wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php, it come out with the error   Could not find package wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability. What do that mean?

Comment: composer require google/cloud-vision

Comment: @RonS, so both are the same? composer require wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php or composer require google/cloud-vision?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use Google's Cloud Vision API, not just *wapnen/google-cloud-vision-php*.

[Here](https://php-download.com/search?q=google%20api%20vision) is the list of all cloud vision API you can find.

Check [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-vision) link you will find it helpful.